# minimum amount of android sdk files needed to build a release apk from command line

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, android-sdk-tools, android-build

I have the android SDK installed on a aws Ubuntu server (14.04).
I have a ruby application which builds an APK and it is working fine on my development environment.

However the android SDK is very large and has taken up half of the space i have availible on the server (4Gb)

All i need from the sdk is to have it run is:

```
./gradlew assembleRelease
```

and sign the apk with a `keystore` using `jarsigner`

As you can see platforms is taking up the bulk of it:

```
:~/sdk/android-sdk-linux$ du -h --max-depth=1 | sort -hr
3.9G    .
2.2G    ./platforms
775M    ./add-ons
469M    ./extras
398M    ./tools
104M    ./build-tools
11M ./platform-tools
4.0K    ./temp
```

Here's a list of what's inside:

```
android-10  android-13  android-16  android-19  android-22  android-8
android-11  android-14  android-17  android-20  android-23  android-9
android-12  android-15  android-18  android-21  android-7   android-N
```

I have already removed the docs directory which almost took up 1Gb but I'm unsure of what else i can remove.
All suggestions are much appreciate, thanks for your time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For `platforms`, you only need whichever one(s) that you are using in your project(s) that you are building. So, examine those project(s) and see what you have for `compileSdkVersion` values. You can remove the `platforms` subdirectories corresponding to ones that you do not need.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, Is it just the compiled SDK version? or everything between minSdkVersion & targetSdkVersion?

`compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.company.appname"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }`

Comment: @PeterG: Just the `compileSdkVersion`.

Comment: thanks, I just tested it, it's working perfectly with just the `compileSdkVersion`. Sorry i didn't reply earlier i ran into more problems that prevented me from fully testing the solution